# Build error in android studio after updating to stable Android studio 3.1.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I was trying to build an application. I was successful in making project(ctrl+F9) after that I tried to run my application on the emulator in this process I got the build error. To fix this issue I got a suggestion from Android studio to change build script to following:

To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint or modify your build script as follows:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release 
         //builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Where could I find the build script? So, that I can change it. I am a newbie to the Android world.

Comment: It's your `build.gradle file`, either in the **project root** or **module level**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build script can be found in the `Gradle Scripts` option in the very left of the screen.

Click the `Gradle scripts` to display all the gradle files and there you will find [image: these files]

These two files marked with red color are the build.gradle files for your project.

Comment: Thank you. It worked! I pasted the suggested code in the build script.

Comment: @KaushalRaj accept the answer by clicking the 'tick' icon so that in future if  other users who have same problem can directly see the answer.

Comment: Already done! If you find my question good, please upvote, I need reputation to upvote answers and to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

try to clean your project, then build it again. if the result still the same, try to invalidates cache & restart.

Comment: My problem is fixed, I pasted the given code in gradle build(app).

Answer (score 0):

Go to android studio then `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...`